# App crashes every time a button is clicked to go to another activity

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity

My app has two buttons and the button with "more info" on it directs to another activity.But if i click on the button it crashes. I have included the activity and the intent on the manifest file.
This is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Integer[] pics = {
            R.drawable.rah,
            R.drawable.rah18a,



    };
    ImageView imageView;
    Button Button1; 
    Button Button2;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Gallery ga = (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.Gallery01);
        ga.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
        Button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);



        Button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("Description.Main.Activity2");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        ga.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, final int pos,
                    long arg3) {


                imageView.setImageResource(pics[pos]);
                Button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(View v) {
                    WallpaperManager wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(v.getContext());
                    try {
                        wm.setResource(pics[pos]);
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                                "Wallpaper has been set", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                  }
                });
            }
        });





            }







    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context ctx;
        int imageBackground;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            ctx = c;
            TypedArray ta = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
            imageBackground = ta.getResourceId(R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 1);
            ta.recycle();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return pics.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {

            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {

            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
            ImageView iv = new ImageView(ctx);
            iv.setImageResource(pics[arg0]);
            iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            iv.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(300,400));
            iv.setBackgroundResource(imageBackground);
            return iv;
        }

    }
}
```

My second activity is called MainActivity2.java and is blank.Help Please.

EDIT: Adding Manifest entry for MainActivity2

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".MainActivity2" >
   <intent-filter> 
     <action android:name="AnotherActivity" /> 
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
   </intent-filter> 
</activity>
```

Here is my logcat:

```
07-22 06:40:37.639: E/AndroidRuntime(770): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 06:40:37.639: E/AndroidRuntime(770): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.rahuldravid/com.example.rahuldravid.MainActivity2}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #2: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
07-22 06:40:37.639: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-22 06:40:37.639: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-22 06:40:37.639: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-22 06:40:37.639: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-22 06:40:37.639: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-22 06:40:37.639: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-22 06:40:37.639: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-22 06:40:37.639: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 06:40:37.639: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-22 06:40:37.639: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-22 06:40:37.639: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-22 06:40:37.639: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-22 06:40:37.639: E/AndroidRuntime(770): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #2: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
07-22 06:40:37.639: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:491)
07-22 06:40:37.639: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:5614)
07-22 06:40:37.639: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:5756)
07-22 06:40:37.639: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(FrameLayout.java:610)
07-22 06:40:37.639: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:554)
07-22 06:40:37.639: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:56)
07-22 06:40:37.639: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:477)
07-22 06:40:37.639: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-22 06:40:37.639: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
07-22 06:40:37.639: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
07-22 06:40:37.639: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
07-22 06:40:37.639: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at com.example.rahuldravid.MainActivity2.onCreate(MainActivity2.java:13)
07-22 06:40:37.639: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-22 06:40:37.639: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-22 06:40:37.639: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-22 06:40:37.639: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  ... 11 more
```

LAYOUT1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/Gallery01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp" />
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="279dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="68dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/bottom_bar"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="1.0dip"
        android:paddingLeft="4.0dip"
        android:paddingRight="4.0dip"
        android:paddingTop="5.0dip" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Set Wallpaper" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="47dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="More Info" />

    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

LAYOUT2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you declare your second activity in the manifest correctly?

Comment: the intent contsructor you are using expects an action, do you have an `intent-filter` for the second activity that matches the action you are using?

Comment: Check the layout of Activity2, does the main layout (the first linearlayout or relativelayout) has width parameter? It is match_parent and you're using it in a <2.1 device?

Comment: Please check your layout xml file as your exception is  You must supply a layout_width attribute. Check and confirm or post your both layout here

Comment: yes i did add the width attribute now but it still seems to crash. i am using it in >2.1 devices.

Answer (score 0):

This line is incorrect

```
Intent intent = new Intent("Description.Main.Activity2");
```

It should be more like

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class); //define the name of your java class 
                                                  //this intent is pointing to
```

EDIT: The line isn't incorrect per se, as an Intent can also take a String action parameter, but it seems that's not what you're going for

Comment: I get the following error The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<MainActivity2>) is undefined

Comment: Please post the logCat with the error in your original post, thanks

Answer (score 0):

please try it this way :

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class); 
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: it still seems to crash! :(